# How set categorySelection a value of return of user funcion in Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news

I have a user function that return a list of categories (f.e. 20, 19) and I want to set in tt_news `categorySelection` as indicate the code

```
plugin.tt_news {
 categorySelection = user_ttNewsCategoriesByUID
 categoryMode = 2
}
```

Before of this I have the user function and works correctly

```
page.105 = USER
page.105 {
  includeLibs = EXT:tt_news/Categorias.php
  userFunc = user_ttNewsInCat
}
```

I am looking but I have not found something. How can I set the return of function in `categorySelection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and works correctly in this way

```
includeLibs.userCategories = EXT:tt_news/Categorias.php

temp.catuid = USER
temp.catuid.preUserFunc = user_ttNewsInCat

plugin.tt_news {    
  categorySelection < temp.catuid
  categoryMode = 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `categorySelection` is `stdWrap` enabled (see [reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/tt_news/ExtNews/Configuration/Reference/Index.html#categoryselection)), you should be able to make use of it like this:

```
plugin.tt_news {
 categorySelection >
 categorySelection.cObject = USER
 categorySelection.cObject.userFunc = user_ttNewsCategoriesByUID
 categoryMode = 2
}
```